# Is there a way to only restart NG+?

Tags: deus-ex-the-fall

In Deus Ex: The Fall (PC), is there a way to only reset the NG+ run? I am trying to go for a Pacifist and maybe 100% and I forgot to get the Tranquilizer Darts.